# I'm trying to use the Logistic Regression classifier and apply it on the UniGram bag-of-words feature set

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, text-classification

so i am trying to use the Logistic Regression classifier and apply it on the UniGram bag-of-words feature set

my code:

clf = sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression()

clf.fit(tf_features_train, train_labels)

print (clf)

error message: This solver needs samples of at least 2 classes in the data, but the data contains only one class: 1

can someone please help me

Answer (score 0):

The message is explicit: check the content of `train_labels`, it contains only class `1`. Normally it should contain at least two different classes, otherwise there's nothing to classify.